# Div on top of another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to put together is basically remaking the YouTube thumbnail with the timestamp at the bottom right of the thumbnail image, like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/T1dXnhP.png]

However, I can't seem to figure out how to make the timestamp go on top of the image and then position it properly.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4162/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="small-video-section">
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
      <img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/yKWoPlL2B8I/mqdefault.jpg" width="220" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-time">
      5:42
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.small-video-section {
  height: 134px;
}

.thumbnail-container {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.thumbnail-last {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.thumbnail-time {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Absolute positioning inside an element is what you are looking for : on [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) or the [internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+absolute+positioning+in+div)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try adding something like this to your `.thumbnail-time` and moving it inside the `.thumbnail-container`:

```
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  bottom:18px;
  right:52px;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4174/)

if you now assign a width to the container (say 220px) and `position:relative;`, you can now add this to your `.thumbnail-time`:

```
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  right:10px;
```

and the time will be positioned always 10px from bottom and right side of the thumbnail.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4191/)

Comment: If I make the time, say 15:34, the box extends outside of the div.

Comment: then try something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4191/ I also updated the answer, to accomodate for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
position: relative;
left: 180px;
bottom: 30px;
```

Adding that to your .thumbnail-time works but it might not be ideal.

Comment: Problem. If I make the text longer, it goes outside of the box.

Comment: float:right would make it grow to the left but you would have to rethink some stuff to make that work. the solution Martin Turjak posted is a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
position:absolute;
```

Also a good idea to add

```
z-index:1000;
```

on the div containing the time.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4181/

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fz-index

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4172/

I'm no expert but it works. If you find a better solution comment and let me know so I can learn as well :)

```
.small-video-section {
    height: 134px;
}
.thumbnail-container {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
}
.thumbnail-last {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.thumbnail-time {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top:20px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Derp, thought you wanted it top left, should be an easy fix though now that they overlap properly.